# Pick two points on the perimeter of a circle of radius 1. Find the expected value of the length of the shortest arc.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Pick two points uniformly randomly on the perimeter of a circle of radius 1. This divides the circle into two pieces. Find the expected value of the length of the shortest piece.

I have no idea to this problem, does anyone could help me? Thank!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your circle at the origin $(0,0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

After you've picked two points, you can always rotate the circle so that one of the points is located at $(-1,0)$, so suppose that we have done so.  Thus, one point is $(-1,0)$ and the other point is chosen randomly from the circle.

The randomly chosen point precisely corresponds to a choice of a number $\theta \in (-\pi /2,\pi /2)$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the $x$-axis and the chord from $(-1,0)$ to the other point.

Denote by $L(\theta )$ the length of the shortest piece for given theta.  Note that $L(\theta )=L(-\theta )$, and so
$$
E:=\frac{1}{\pi}\int _{-\pi /2}^{\pi /2}\mathrm{d}\theta \, L(\theta )=\frac{2}{\pi}\int _0^{\pi /2}\mathrm{d}\theta \, L(\theta ),
$$
where $E$ is of course the expected value, the number we would like to compute.  Thus, it suffices to calculate $L(\theta )$ for $\theta$ positive.

Draw two radii from the center, one to the $(-1,0)$ point and one to the other random point.  This should form an isosceles triangle with two angles $\theta$ and one angle $\pi -2\theta$.

As the radius of the circle is $1$ and the angle that cuts out the arc we are concerned about is $\pi -2\theta$, the length of the arc is $1\cdot (\pi -2\theta )=\pi -2\theta$

Hence,
$$
E=\frac{2}{\pi}\int _0^{\pi /2}\mathrm{d}\theta \, [\pi -2\theta ]=\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{\pi ^2}{4}=\frac{\pi}{2}.
$$
This, of course, makes perfect intuitive sense.

Comment: I think I got your idea, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Treat the circle as an interval with ends identified. You've then got a function $f$ on 
$$
X = [0, 2\pi] \times [0, 2\pi]
$$
which assigns to a pair $(s, t)$ the length of the smaller arc between $s$ and $t$.

Note that $X$ is a probability space in a natural way. The interval $I = [0, 2\pi]$ is a probability space, with a uniform probability measure with density $\frac{1}{2\pi}$. The space $X$ is just the product $I \times I$ with the product density, $\frac{1}{4 \pi^2}$. To find the expected value of a random variable $f$ on $X$, we integrate $f$ times this density, i.e., we compute
$$
E[f] = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(x, y) \frac{1}{4 \pi^2} ~dx~dy.
$$

Returning to the function $(s, t) \mapsto f(s, t)$ itself: This function is piecewise linear in $s$ and $t$. You might want to make a graph of it. Once you do that, you can integrate it over the square, and divide by the area of the square ($4 \pi^2$) to get its average value as above.

I'll get you started. Let's look at $f(s, t)$ for the case $s = 0$. 
$$
f(0, t) = \begin{cases} t & 0 \le t \le \pi\\
2\pi - t & \pi \le t \le 2\pi
\end{cases}
$$

What about when $s = \pi/4$? 
$$
f(\pi/4, t) = \begin{cases} t-\pi/4 & \pi/4 \le t \le 3\pi/4\\
2\pi - (t-\pi/4) & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

You might then ask "What happens when I integrate these with respect to $t$, and then integrate the result with respect to $s$?" (I'm using Fubini's theorem here, which says that to integrate over an area, it's OK to do the integral one variable at a time, provided that the function you're integrating is nice enough; $f$ is.)

Added after comments:

I pointed out that you want to compute
$$
\frac{1}{4\pi^2} \iint_0^{2\pi}  f(s, t) dt ds
$$
To do so, I propose that you compute
$$
\frac{1}{4\pi^2} \int_0^{2\pi} \left(\int_0^{2\pi} f(s, t) dt\right) ds
$$
The inner integral
$$
u(s) = \int_0^{2\pi} f(s, t) dt
$$
depends on $s$. But looking at the case where $s = 0$, it's clear that the value of $f$ increases from $0$ to $\pi$ on one half-circle, and decreases from $\pi$ to $0$ on the other, for an average value of $\pi/2$ over the whole circle (i.e., as $t$ goes from $0$ to $2 \pi$.). The value of $u(0)$ is therefore $(\pi/2) 2 \pi = \pi^2$.

What about $u(\pi/4)$? On the interval from $0$ to $3\pi/4$, $f$ increases from $0$ to $\pi$; on the complementary portion of the circle, it decreases from $\pi$ to $0$. Again the average value is $\pi/2$, and the integral over the whole interval is $\pi^2$.

The same argument holds for every $s$, so $u(s)$ is in fact the constant $\pi^2$. Thus our double-integral of $f$ reduces to 
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{4\pi^2} \iint_0^{2\pi}  f(s, t) dt ds &= 
\frac{1}{4\pi^2} \int_0^{2\pi}  u(s) ds \\
&= \frac{1}{4\pi^2} \int_0^{2\pi}  \pi^2 ds\\
&= \frac{1}{4\pi^2} \int_0^{2\pi}  \pi^2 ds\\
&= \frac{1}{4\pi^2} \pi^2 \int_0^{2\pi}   ds\\
&= \frac{1}{4} \int_0^{2\pi}   ds\\
&= \frac{1}{4} 2\pi\\
&= \frac{\pi}{2}.
\end{align}

Comment: S can be any point in the circle, why you pick s=0 and pi/2, or you mean I need to integrate s on the whole circle? If it is, then I can understand why I should integrate s, but yeah, you are right,I want to ask what happen if I integrate respect to t?

Comment: See the extended answer above, following the words "Added after comments:".

Comment: I could understand that f(s,t) is the shortest piece, but I don't get that why the expectation is double integral of s and t, and then over the square. Since, the expectation should be the integral of the shortest length times the correspondent probability, and that's what Jonathan Gleason's answer I think. I'm still trying to understand what your idea is.

Comment: I've added a little more detail near the top. My answer is the same as Jonathan's, except that I don't rotate the first point to $(-1,0)$; instead, I consider the first point could be anywhere (that's the variable $s$) and average over all possible values of $s$ (that's the integral with the 'ds'). Since the thing I'm averaging wrt $s$ turns out to be constant, that integration is easy (the last set of displayed equations in my answer). But if you're happy with Jonathan's answer, there's no reason to slog through mine.

Comment: I got it, thanks very much