# Task on mix of calculus with probably probability

Tags: calculus, probability, reference-request, terminology, book-recommendation

I have this task to solve:

A father suggests two algorithms to divide a round pie between his sons: A) The elder son gets 2/3, and the younger son gets 1/3; B) The pie is cut along the line passing through two points chosen at random at its circumference, and the younger son gets the smaller piece. Which algorithm gives a larger mathematical expectation of the younger son's part?

> EDIT: I have a brutal error below. My only question is:
>   What is the name of this class of problems? What topic should I read to be able to solve these?

To model algorithm B):
Let's take just half a circle and put it on a graph in such a way that the first randomly chosen point lies exactly at (0,0). Let radius $r = 1$

[Circle and a line dividing it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/it4hV.png)

Then let's choose another random point and define the equations for these functions:

$y_l = kx$ for the green line, $b = 0$ because $y_l(0) = 0$

$y_c = \sqrt{1 - (x - 1)^2}, y > 0, x > 0$ for the red line-circumference,
where the first `1` is radius

The $S$ area on the graph is equal to the part which will be given to the younger brother.

Then the area of $S$ must be equal

> EDIT: the error is in subtracting $\int_0^2 y_l \mathrm{d}x$
>   as this subtracts extra area in the top-right corner

\begin{align*}
S &= \int_0^2 y_c \mathrm{d}x - \int_0^2 y_l \mathrm{d}x \\
& = \int_0^2 \sqrt{1 - (x - 1)^2} \mathrm{d}x - \int_0^2 kx \mathrm{d}x \\
& \text{let's substitute} \, 
x - 1 = sin(u) \:\text{and}\: \mathrm{d}x = cos(u)\mathrm{d}u \:
\text{for 1st eq. and keep int. intervals as a and b for simplicity} \\
& = \int_a^b \sqrt{1 - sin^2(u)}\:cos(u)\mathrm{d}u - (\frac{kx^2}{2})|_0^2 \\
& = \int_a^b cos^2(u)\mathrm{d}u - (\frac{kx^2}{2})|_0^2 \\
& = \int_b^b (\frac{1}{2} + \frac{cos(2u)}{2}) \mathrm{d}u - 
(\frac{kx^2}{2})|_0^2 \\
& = (\frac{1}{2}u - \frac{sin(2u)}{4})|_a^b - (\frac{kx^2}{2})|_0^2 \\
& \mid\:sin(2u) = 2sin(u)cos(u) = 2sin(u)\sqrt{1 - sin^2(u)}\:\mid \\
& = (\frac{arcsin(x-1)}{2} - \frac{(x - 1)\sqrt{1-(x-1)^2}}{2})|_0^2
- (\frac{kx^2}{2})|_0^2 \\
& = [(\frac{\pi}{4} - 0) - (\frac{-\pi}{4} - 0)] - (2k -0) \\
& = \frac{\pi}{2} - 2k
\end{align*}

So I have that in the algorithm A) the younger son gets 1/3 of a circle,
$S_c = \pi \times 1^2 = \pi$, so it's $\frac{\pi}{3}$.

In the algorithm B) the younger son gets $S(k) = \frac{\pi}{2} - 2k$.

And the question is: Which algorithm gives a larger mathematical expectation of the younger son's part?

I have 2 questions:

1. Where do I go from there?
2. What is the name of this class of problems? What topic should I read to be
   able to solve these?

Comment: You wrote: "Which algorithm gives a larger mathematical expectation of the younger son's part?"  Are you *sure* this is the question?  Or is the question possibly, "Is the second algorithm more likely to give the younger son more than $1/3$ of the pie, or less?"  ETA: It could be either.  I just want to be sure that we're answering the right question.

Comment: @BrianTung yes, I have just checked it. Though your proposed question seems as a better restatement of the original question, I also had this thought in mind.

Comment: might be helpful https://everipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)

Comment: Exact same problem ,different wording https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1011234/pick-two-points-on-the-perimeter-of-a-circle-of-radius-1-find-the-expected-valu

Comment: @Jonas12 thank you for taking your time and finding similar problem! Bertrand paradox is interesting as well!

Comment: Skoltech Test  Preparation :)

Comment: @Jonas12 true ;)

Comment: Can you add me on LinkedIn , you can get info on my stack profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem of [geometric probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_probability) (not to be confused with the [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)). There's a [geometric-probability](/questions/tagged/geometric-probability) tag here on math.SE with $348$ questions that you can look at to get ideas for such problems.